# Is there a way to choose where you start in XCom 2?

Tags: xcom-2

Can you choose your starting region (or at least starting continent), or is it always random?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no way to choose your starting region.

But that said, there's also no real point outside of "RP reasons"; the resistance connections and even the continent bonuses are randomized in each playthrough, so regardless of where you start, you're not "closer" or "farther" to anything in particular.